# How to use lvg ansible module to resize a volume group on top?

Tags: ansible

In the Ansible [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/lvg_module.html) for lvg, i see that there is a pvresize parameter to resize the physical volume to the maximum available size.

I have this playbook :

```
- name: pvresize 
  community.general.lvg:
    vg: file_data
    pvs: /dev/sdb
    pvresize: yes   
  become: true
```

I increase the size of my disk under VMWare (60G to 65G for example) and I run this playbook

I have no errors or changes... Just OK, but my VG is still 60G

If i use **pvresize /dev/sdb** on my VM it works

I tested on Centos 7 and 8 with the same result. I use Ansible 2.9.10 and community.general 1.2.0

What am I not doing right?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a little extra information like relevant log information coming out of -vvv execution of your playbook?, at the same time, can you provide information about the status of the disk before and after increasing the size? like fdisk

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with a full example providing the scenario with the previous and final status of the VG.

Coming from the following:

```
# vgs|grep test
  testvg      1   1   0 wz--n-  <5.00g    0

# pvs |grep test
  /dev/sde1  testvg    lvm2 a--   <5.00g    0

# lvs |grep test
  testlv    testvg    -wi-ao----  <5.00g
```

If you execute the following ansible playbook after increasing the size of the partition to 10G(simulating your scenario):

```
---
- hosts: all
  user: 'awesomeuser'
  become: true
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
   
  - name: Resize existing pv
    community.general.lvg:
      vg: testvg
      pvs: /dev/sde1
      pvresize: yes
```

you will end up with:

```
# vgs|grep test
  testvg      1   1   0 wz--n- <10.00g 5.00g
```

Notice that vg is bigger 10G and it has 5g free, and pv is bigger too:

```
# pvs |grep -i test
  /dev/sde1  testvg    lvm2 a--  <10.00g 5.00g
```

As a plus if you wanted to increase the size of the filesystem in case of having one:

```
- name: Extend the logical volume to take all remaining space of the PVs and resize the underlying filesystem
  community.general.lvol:
    vg: testvg
    lv: testlv
    size: 100%PVS
    resizefs: true
```